# Example of delayed column generation

Tags: algorithm, math, linear-programming

Can someone point me to a small example of how [delayed column generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_column-generation) works for the [cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem). I have found several sources that describe it abstractly but I still don't understand exactly what it does or how to implement it in a program. A step by step example of it with a small set of numbers would be helpful.

For example, say I have inventory of pieces of pipe of varying lengths:

> 12, 25

And a customer requests pipe of the following lengths:

> 5, 10

Now say a pipe of length x has a value of x<sup>1.2</sup>. I want to maximize the value of what is left in inventory after making the cuts for the customer. How exactly would column generation be used to find a nearly optimal answer?

Comment: Googling for `cutting stock problem delayed column-generation` seems to have shown up a lot of implementations. Have you searched exhaustively yet?

Comment: (for example, http://www.delphiforfun.org/programs/Cutting%20Stock.htm has source code and a good explanation)

Comment: I have seen that page and that is where I got most of what I understand but it is still a rather general description of what is going on. I would like to see an example of the process step by step.

Answer (score 3):

We start with a sad-looking master LP that has only the Phase I slack variables `z5` and `z10`.

```
minimize z5 + z10
subject to
z5 >= 1 (y5)
z10 >= 1 (y10)
z5, z10 >= 0
```

`y5` is the constraint that we cut enough pipe of length 5, and `y10` is the constraint that we cut enough pipe of length 10. The primal solution is `z5=1, z10=1`, and the optimal dual solution is `y5=1, y10=1`. Viewed differently, the current price of both a 5-pipe and a 10-pipe is 1. Since this is Phase I, our inventory costs nothing, and solving a knapsack problem for each pipe length in inventory (with time savings if you use the classic DP because it generates a table for all smaller lengths), the greatest profit margin is to cut a 25-pipe into five 5-pipes. Let variable `x5,5,5,5,5` be the number of cuts of this type.

```
minimize z5 + z10
subject to
5 x5,5,5,5,5 + z5 >= 1 (y5)
z10 >= 1 (y10)
x5,5,5,5,5, z5, z10 >= 0
```

Now the optimal primal solution is `x5,5,5,5,5=0.2, z5=0, z10=1`. The price of 5-pipe is 0, and the price of 10-pipe is 1. We're still not primal-feasible, so our inventory still costs nothing. The optimal patterns at current prices are `x10,10` (waste 5) and `x10,10,5`. Let's not be wasteful.

```
minimize z5 + z10
subject to
5 x5,5,5,5,5 + x10,10,5 + z5 >= 1 (y5)
2 x10,10,5 + z10 >= 1 (y10)
x5,5,5,5,5, x10,10,5, z5, z10 >= 0
```

The optimal primal solution is `x5,5,5,5,5=0.1, x10,10,5=0.5, z5=0, z10=0`. All of the slack variables are 0, so it's time for Phase II.

```
minimize 25^1.2 x5,5,5,5,5 + 25^1.2 x10,10,5
subject to
5 x5,5,5,5,5 + x10,10,5 >= 1 (y5)
2 x10,10,5 >= 1 (y10)
x5,5,5,5,5, x10,10,5 >= 0
```

Here's the dual program.

```
maximize y5 + y10
subject to
5 y5 <= 25^1.2
y5 + 2 y10 <= 25^1.2
y5, y10 >= 0
```

The optimal primal solution is still `x5,5,5,5,5=0.1, x10,10,5=0.5`. The optimal dual solution is `y5=25^1.2 * 0.2` (about 9.5) and `y10=25^1.2 * 0.4` (about 19.0). Since we're in Phase II, the 12-pipe now costs 12^1.2 (about 19.7), and the 25-pipe, 25^1.2 (about 47.6). If we cut a 12-pipe and waste 2, the cost is 12^1.2 - 2^1.2 (about 17.4).

Currently, there's no profit in cutting a 25-pipe. In cutting the 12-pipe, however, we expend about 17.4 to get either two 5-pipes or one 10-pipe. Either way, the current total price is about 19.0, which means a positive profit. I'd put one of the columns in and solve again, but I'm getting tired and simply will tell you that the final optimal primal is `x5,5=0.5, x10=1` (both cuts on the 12-pipe).

Notice that, while this solution is fractionally optimal, if the customer literally wants exactly one 5-pipe and one 10-pipe, then we have some more thinking to do. In fact, there will be waste over and above the LP solution if and only if the customer wants an odd number of each pipe, but, regardless of total customer demand, the waste is at most one 5-pipe, which is why we say that this answer is "nearly optimal".